# what do these lines of code do? It involves pointers and arrays

Tags: c++

I am new to C and C++ and I have only worked with arrays and multidimensional arrays in the Java language.
I am trying to migrate some code and I need to know what these lines mean:

```
int rows = 100; 
int columns = 10;
int i,j;
double *example = new double[rows*columns];
File fileEx = fopen("exampleText.txt","r");
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
        fscanf(fileEx, "%lf", example+columns*i+j);
        //printf("%f ", *(example+columns*i+j));
    }
```

Thanks very much...help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which lines, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: If I were you, I would get a good book on C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is reading a 2-D array of `double` values, one at a time.

The `example + columns*i + j` is producing a pointer to the right element of the array on each iteration.

Having said that, the array is allocated as a 1-D array, and the program is going to be doing the subscripting using a calculation each time it accesses an element of the array.

The code should check that the `File` (is that a typo for `FILE`?) is opened successfully before using it.  It would not be a bad idea to check that the `fscanf()` succeeds on each iteration too.

Comment: Oh i see! since it was my first time seeing pointers, I thought coloumns*i and rows*columns were some sort of pointer functions, rather than simple multiplication. Thanks so much!...for some reason, it seems i cannot choose this as the correct answer on this computer...i'll check this as correct when i get home...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code read a 2D array represented as a 1D array in a file.

```
double *example = new double[rows*columns];
```

This line actually allocate space in memory for you array. So basically, `example` will refer to the base address of you array in memory. By doing something like `example + 4` your accessing the address of your array + 32 bytes. Indeed, the sum applies on the type of your array: here 8 bytes (The size of a double) for each cell, so +4 means 4 * 8 = 32 bytes.

If you were to have a int (4 bytes) array, the +4 would have meant you're accessing the address + 16 bytes as 4 * 4 bytes = 16 bytes.

In easiest word, by doing `example + 4` you're just going to 4th cell in the array, it would be like writting `example[3]` because each cell actually holds a Double (so 8 bytes), and by doing `address + 32` your skipping the first 3 elements.

```
fscanf(fileEx, "%lf", example+columns*i+j);
```

Knowing that, this line simply means your putting the current character in the cell `columns * i + j` like you would do in any other language.